# insert html into string at several positions at the same time

Tags: html, ruby

So I have a Peptide, which is a string of letters, corresponding to aminoacids
Say the peptide is

```
peptide_sequence = "VEILANDQGNR"
```

And it has a modification on **L** at position **4** and **R** at position **11**,

I would like to insert a `"<span class=\"modified_aa\">` and `</span>` before and after those positions at the same time.

Here is what I tried:

My modifications are stored in an array `pep_mods` of objects modification containing an attribute location with the position, in this case 4 and 11

```
pep_mods.each do |m|
  peptide_sequence.gsub(peptide_sequence[m.position.to_i-1], "<span class=\"mod\">#{@peptide_sequence[m.location.to_i-1]}</span>" )
end
```

But since there are two modifications after the first insert of the html span tag the positions in the string become all different

How could I achieve what I intend to do? I hope it was clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Floris's answer is correct, but if you want to do it the hard way (`O(n^2)` instead of `O(nlgn)`) here is the basic idea.

Instead of relying on `gsub` you can iterate over the characters checking if each has an index corresponding to one of the modifications. If the index matches, perform the modification. Otherwise, keep the original character.

```
modified = peptide_sequence.each_with_index
                           .to_a 
                           .map do |c, i|
                              pep_mods.each do |m|
                                if m.location.to_i = i
                                  %Q{<span class="mod">#{c}</span>}
                                else
                                  c
                                end
                              end
                          end.join('')
```

Answer (score 3):

You should work backwards- make the modification starting with the last one. That way the index of earlier modifications is unchanged.

You might need to sort the array of indices in reverse order - then you can use the code you currently have.

Comment: hey, that sounds clever, i will give that a try

Comment: It is quite a common trick - used in general when you are looping over an array of objects, and modifying as you go along. Iterators get confused when you change the thing they are iterating over - but never when you work backwards... Deleting elements from an array is a classical example, but it works equally for inserting.

Comment: but it is not that easy because the positions and letters in the string may be variable,  even adjacent, that is why i am looping through an object with the stored letters and positions.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, just in case this is helpful for anyone else, this is how I finally did it:

I first converted the peptide sequence to an array :

```
pep_seq_arr = peptide_sequence.split("")
```

then used `each_with_index` as Casey mentioned

```
pep_seq_arr.each_with_index do |aa, i|
  pep_mods.each do |m|
    pep_seq_arr[i] = "<span class='mod'>#{aa}</span>" if i == m.location.to_i-1
  end
end
```

and finally joined the array:

```
pep_seq_arr.join
```

It was easier than I first thought